# Using argon2 in an android app gives an UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, android, hash

I want to use [Argon2](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2) in this Android app I am trying to make. The README section of that repository listed [this](https://github.com/phxql/argon2-jvm) as an official JVM binding and I proceeded to include it in my app. I did this by including the given code in my gradle file[1]. I wrote some sample code to utilize this library[2] but on running the code, it throws a `Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` and exits. Can someone throw some light on how to fix this for me?

[1]:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/phxql/maven"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'de.mkammerer:argon2-jvm:1.2'
}
```

[2]:

```
Argon2 argon2 = Argon2Factory.create();
String hash = argon2.hash(10, 65536, 2, "Hello World");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that this particular library doesn't possess an implementation compiled for ARM architectures. The wait continues for one then, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

A valid ARM implementation from Andreas Gadermaier is found in https://github.com/andreas1327250/argon2-java. I tested it with Argon2 i, with a Raspberry Pi 3, and works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Signal now has an Argon2 Android wrapper around the c implementation: https://github.com/signalapp/Argon2

Comment: How did you import it?

Comment: The gradle import line is in the link and everything is in the org.signal.argon2 package

Comment: Thanks. Actually while importing, I missed to add .*; It worked then. (Silly mistake :-) ) Thanks for pointing to the library.